# NLP to identify questions from various strings

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a robust API/NLP library which can idntify from a no. of strings which one is a question and which one is not.
Is there any quick api that can tell me about it ?
There were no robust apis/nlp's I can find for it, except sentiments api which will not serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can create your own parsing algorithm for any standard words that occur in questions.
Like `what`, `should`, `?`, etc.
But as far as I can understand there do not exist any standard library for parsing and identifying questions.

Comment: Paid services like : http://www.123pas.com/proposal-mgmt.html.
Not endorsing it although, just a finding.